# Does Injector create a new instance of the service with ActivatedRoute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

### Background

I am using inheritance in Angular, the major issue was that I initially had to pass services from parent to child, something like

```js
  // Parent
  export class ParentComponent {
   protected myService: MyService;
   constructor(private myService: MyService) {
   }
  }
  // Child
  export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  
   constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    super(myService);
   }
  }
```

To avoid this I found a different approach using `Injector` from `@angular/core`. In this approach we follow the below steps

Create a service

app-injector-service.ts

```js
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

export class AppInjectorService {
  private static injector: Injector;

  static setInjector(injector: Injector) {
    AppInjectorService.injector = injector;
  }
  static getInjector(): Injector {
    return AppInjectorService.injector;
  }
}
```

in the main.ts file

```js
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then((ref) => {
    AppInjectorService.setInjector(ref.injector);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

and parent class file would look like

```js
export abstract class ParentComponent {
  protected myService: MyService;
  constructor() {
    const injector = AppInjectorService.getInjector();
    this.myService = injector.get(MyService);
  }
}
```

With this approach, no need to pass service to the super call! Amazing

### My Issue

The approach above worked very well untill I needed to extract the route param from the activated route so I followed the same structure. To my surprise It is not working. I tested with manually injecting the `ActivatedRoute` in the child class and the parameter exists. I dont understand why the parameter is not available in the class when we inject `ActivatedRoute` using the `AppInjector`. Ofcourse I can go back to injecting it in the child class then passing it to the super function so that it can be accessed by the Parent class but this is what I was trying to avoid...

Below is a stackblitz demo showing the issue, click on the route and you will notice that we get back `null` from the ActivatedRoute injected in the parent class but a value in the ActivatedRoute in the child class. Basically I am trying to find if there is anything am doing wrong or is there something am missing while using the Injector

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bu5kqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-injector.service.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fparent.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html)

Comment: In your first example do you want MyService to exist once for each parent component, and that same instance to be used by each parents children?

Comment: @wlf yes. I have updated the Demo to show this. If 2 components extends the parent, they will both use the same instance of the service. For some reason this is not the case for ActivatedRoute

Comment: ActivatedRoute should be a singleton service across the app. Can't you just inject it normally into both your parent and child constructors individually?

Comment: Also it's unlikely you need to use your first approach for other services, rather you should provide them at component level in the parent.

Comment: @wlf I don't think that `ActivatedRoute` is singleton since is embedded in `RouterModule` and this could be imported `forRoot()` and `forChild()`. Also it depends somehow on the `outlet` that renders the component, and my guess is that this is the problem here. I `console.log()` both `ActivatedRoute` services and they are different.

Comment: Also happens to me that this apporach with the `injector` and `myService` only works when `myService` is `providedIn: root`. I tried to register `myService` in the `ParentComponent` array of `providers` and get a `NullInjectorError`.

Comment: @wlf, the reason am trying to inject it in the parent only is to avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code: using inheritance for components and using a non-singleton service as a singleton service.

you are setting up injector in your service `AppInjectorService.setInjector(ref.injector);` after app is bootstrapped but what happens when one of your component is directly used in your root component(AppComponent) and that component inherited that parent comp class, as you are using injector inside parent to resolve all required dependencies, it won't work because you do not have access to injector by that time, setting up injector in constructor using that static method is a bad idea because constructors of components can be invoked even though they are not being rendered yet and they also may be called during some bootstrapping process so you see the problem? your parent component's constructor is called before `AppInjectorService.setInjector(ref.injector);`. This may have worked if all the components inheriting your parent component were initialized  lazily/dynamically so that app is bootstraped and your injector is setup in your service before using it.
Inheritance is a bitch, especially with components it'll bite you in the ass sooner or later, use DI to reduce repetitive code, in your case you can create a service that can contain all the required dependencies and inject it into whatever component you want to, the lines of code to inherit a component vs injecting a service are typically the same though this comes with the limitation that you can't mix and match services of different scopes(Singletons/Module level/Component level) but that is expected to be honest.

Second problem is using a contextual service out of context, ActivatedRoute is meant to be injected into components that are part of route config, let's takte example of this config:

`{ path: ":id", component: ChildComponent }`

if you inject ActivatedRoute into `ChildComponent`, it'll work as expected but if you inject it into `AppComponent`, it won't work it's not gonna throw any errors but when you'll try to listen to changes in `paramMap`, you won't get it because it `AppComponent` is not connected to that specific path. If you want to globally listen to changes in route then prefer `Router`.

One thing to note here, when you pass that route config to RouterModule, it'll now be responsible for creating instances of components based on route path and it can then inject an injector with a newly created dependency(like ActivatedRoute) into that component so injecting dependencies like those anywhere may not work.

Comment: Are you saying using inheritance is a problem?

Comment: @OwenKelvin yes

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: logically it may not make sense in some scenarios, you need to make sure that those child components do actually form a "is a" relationship with parent component. Other thing is the demo you shared, its throwing null ref error because of improper order of execution, your parent class is trying to read instance of `ActivatedRoute` in it's constructor using injector but that injector itself is not available yet, it'll be set after app is bootstrapped and this out of ordering is because constructor of component is getting invoked before storing instance of injector in AppInjectorService